# OpenMP and exporting parallelized functions within DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2015, parallel-processing, openmp, dllexport, mql4

I have a function within DLL that uses OpenMP to parallelize few loops. The functions have been tested/exported by calling them from an app built in C++ and everything works nicely. I then export the functions to another platform ( MetaTrader Terminal 4 which uses `MQL4` programming language) where the code also works but substantially slower (please see the piece of code below where OpenMP is being used). So my best guess is that parallelization is not working while calling from the platform. I am using Visual Studio 2015 for my project though.

```
            double dtime;
            dtime = omp_get_wtime();

            ofstream fopen("C:\\output.txt", 'a');
            ofstream fout("C:\\output.txt", 'a');

            dtime = omp_get_wtime();


#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(num)
            for (int p = 1; p <= r1; p++) {
                int k = omp_get_thread_num();
                int i = I1[p], j = i + l;
                double alpha = 0, beta = 0, gamma = 0;
                double zeta, t, c, s;
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                    alpha = alpha + (U_t[i][k] * U_t[i][k]);
                    beta = beta + (U_t[j][k] * U_t[j][k]);
                    gamma = gamma + (U_t[i][k] * U_t[j][k]);
                }
                C[k] = max(C[k], abs(gamma) / sqrt(alpha*beta));
                //converge = max(converge, abs(gamma)/sqrt(alpha*beta));    //compute convergence
                //basicaly is the angle
                //between column i and j


                zeta = (beta - alpha) / (2.0 * gamma);
                t = sgn(zeta) / (abs(zeta) + sqrt(1.0 + (zeta*zeta)));        //compute tan of angle
                c = 1.0 / (sqrt(1.0 + (t*t)));              //extract cos
                s = c*t;                            //extrac sin


                for (int k = 0; k<N; k++) {

                    t = U_t[i][k];

                    U_t[i][k] = c*t - s*U_t[j][k];
                    if (!(U_t[i][k] < 0 || U_t[i][k] > 0)) {
                        U_t[i][k] = 0;
                    }

                    U_t[j][k] = s*t + c*U_t[j][k];
                    if (!(U_t[j][k] < 0 || U_t[j][k] > 0)) {
                        U_t[j][k] = 0;
                    }

                
                    t = V_t[i][k];

                    V_t[i][k] = c*t - s*V_t[j][k];
                    if (!(V_t[i][k] < 0 || V_t[i][k] > 0)) {
                        V_t[i][k] = 0;
                    }

                    V_t[j][k] = s*t + c*V_t[j][k];
                    if (!(V_t[j][k] < 0 || V_t[j][k] > 0)) {
                        V_t[j][k] = 0;
                    }

                }
            }
            fout << endl;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(num)
            for (int p = 1; p <= r2; p++) {
                int k = omp_get_thread_num();
                int i = I2[p], j = i + l;
                double alpha = 0, beta = 0, gamma = 0;
                double zeta, t, c, s;
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                    alpha = alpha + (U_t[i][k] * U_t[i][k]);
                    beta = beta + (U_t[j][k] * U_t[j][k]);
                    gamma = gamma + (U_t[i][k] * U_t[j][k]);
                }
                C[k] = max(C[k], abs(gamma) / sqrt(alpha*beta));
                //converge = max(converge, abs(gamma)/sqrt(alpha*beta));    //compute convergence
                //basicaly is the angle
                //between column i and j

                zeta = (beta - alpha) / (2.0 * gamma);
                t = sgn(zeta) / (abs(zeta) + sqrt(1.0 + (zeta*zeta)));        //compute tan of angle
                c = 1.0 / (sqrt(1.0 + (t*t)));              //extract cos
                s = c*t;                            //extrac sin


                for (int k = 0; k<N; k++) {


                    t = U_t[i][k];

                    U_t[i][k] = c*t - s*U_t[j][k];
                    if (!(U_t[i][k] < 0 || U_t[i][k] > 0)) {
                        U_t[i][k] = 0;
                    }

                    U_t[j][k] = s*t + c*U_t[j][k];
                    if (!(U_t[j][k] < 0 || U_t[j][k] > 0)) {
                        U_t[j][k] = 0;
                    }



                    t = V_t[i][k];

                    V_t[i][k] = c*t - s*V_t[j][k];
                    if (!(V_t[i][k] < 0 || V_t[i][k] > 0)) {
                        V_t[i][k] = 0;
                    }

                    V_t[j][k] = s*t + c*V_t[j][k];
                    if (!(V_t[j][k] < 0 || V_t[j][k] > 0)) {
                        V_t[j][k] = 0;
                    }


                }

            }
            fout << endl;
            for (int k = 0; k < num; k++)
                converge = max(converge, C[k]);
            fout << endl;
            if (l == M) {
                fout << converge << '\t';

                fout << endl;
                dtime = omp_get_wtime() - dtime;
                fout << "\n" << "dtime: " << dtime << " ";
                dtime = omp_get_wtime();
                fout << endl;

            }
            fout << endl; 
            fout.close();
```

These are outputs for convergence and time taken:

C++ app:

```
0.999996    dtime: 7.91817e-05
0.954982    dtime: 8.01593e-05
0.964351    dtime: 0.000116817
0.934475    dtime: 7.86929e-05
0.781737    dtime: 7.77154e-05
0.812496    dtime: 7.96705e-05
0.500925    dtime: 7.77154e-05
0.174739    dtime: 7.77154e-05
0.0407444   dtime: 7.86929e-05 
0.0137945   dtime: 8.01593e-05 
0.0039458   dtime: 0.000136857 
0.000550945 dtime: 7.86929e-05 
0.000149865 dtime: 7.96705e-05 
3.76775e-05 dtime: 7.96705e-05 
6.86001e-06 dtime: 8.0648e-05 
2.04005e-06 dtime: 7.82042e-05 
5.6817e-07  dtime: 8.84685e-05 
2.70614e-07 dtime: 7.96705e-05
5.78656e-08 dtime: 7.86929e-05
1.90527e-08 dtime: 8.01593e-05
1.00316e-09 dtime: 7.96705e-05
```

From the platform:

```
0.999997    dtime: 0.222026
0.917038    dtime: 0.219041
0.982879    dtime: 0.215614
0.723091    dtime: 0.219034
0.295653    dtime: 0.215915
0.097825    dtime: 0.21803
0.0350881   dtime: 0.21804
0.00654856  dtime: 0.219009
0.00188476  dtime: 0.217366
0.000435981 dtime: 0.223172
9.50818e-05 dtime: 0.21804
2.27348e-05 dtime: 0.260625
1.39124e-05 dtime: 0.219027
1.72161e-06 dtime: 0.218035
3.18178e-07 dtime: 0.218927
1.77708e-07 dtime: 0.218026
3.81575e-08 dtime: 0.204294
9.53867e-09 dtime: 0.221036
```

---

**`MQL4`** function declarations:

```
#property                                                  copyright "Adrijus"
#property                                                  version   "1.00"
#property strict
#import  "LMBRDLL.dll"
                      double  getWeights( double &data[],
                                          int    &topology[],
                                          int     topSize,
                                          double &TV[],
                                          double  validationDifference,
                                          int     vSize,
                                          int     timeSteps,
                                          int     nVabs,
                                          double &weights[]
                                          );
                      
                      double testWeights( double &weights[],
                                          double &currentData[],
                                          int    &topology[],
                                          int     topSize,
                                          int     timeSteps,
                                          int     nVabs
                                          );
#import
#include <stdlib.mqh>
```

---

**`MQL4`** function calls:

```
                 getWeights( data,
                             topology,
                             topSize,
                             TV,
                             validationDifference,
                             vSize,
                             timeSteps,
                             nVabs,
                             weights
                             );
double output = testWeights( weights,      // DLL function returns predicted percentage change
                             currentData,
                             topology,
                             topSize,
                             timeSteps,
                             nVabs
                             );
```

---

Definitions in the **`DLL`**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

double *getWeights( double const *idata,
                    int    const *aTopology,
                    int           topSize,
                    double const *aTV,
                    double        validationDifference,
                    int           vSize,
                    int           tSteps,
                    int           nVabs,
                    double       *T
                    ) {

    vector<unsigned> topology(topSize);
    for (i = 0; i < topSize; i++) {
        topology[i] = aTopology[i];
    }
    
    vector<double> TV(2);
    TV[0] = aTV[0];
    TV[1] = aTV[1];

    Matrix inputVals = buildInputs(idata, vSize, tSteps, nVabs);
    inputVals = sortInputs(inputVals, TV);
    sortTargets(TV);
    Matrix targetVals = getTargets();
    Net myNet(topology, inputVals);

    double currentValidationError = 1000000000777;
    double previousValidationError = 1000000000000000;
    double difference = 1;

    while (currentValidationError < previousValidationError) {

        difference = previousValidationError - currentValidationError;

        if (difference < validationDifference)
            break;

        FeedForward(&topology, &myNet);

        Backpropagation(&topology, &myNet, &targetVals);

        BuildJacobian(&topology, &myNet);
    
        LevenberMarquardtBeyesianRegularization( &topology,
                                                 &myNet,
                                                 &targetVals
                                                  );
        previousValidationError = currentValidationError;
    
        currentValidationError = Validation( &myNet.allLMweights,
                                              topology
                                              );

        //UpdateSynapses(topology, myNet);
    }

    vector<double> rowWeights = buildRWeights(myNet.allSynapses);

    for (i = 0; i < rowWeights.size(); i++) {
        T[i] = rowWeights[i];
    }

    return T;
}

double testWeights( double const *rowWeights,
                    double const *testData,
                    int    const *aTopology,
                    int           topSize,
                    int           timeSteps,
                    int           nVariables
                    ) {

    vector<unsigned> topology(topSize);
    for (i = 0; i < topSize; i++) {
        topology[i] = aTopology[i];
    }

    vector<Matrix> testWeights = buildWeightMatrices( rowWeights,
                                                      topology
                                                      );
    vector<double> input = buildTestInputs( testData,
                                            timeSteps,
                                            nVariables
                                            );
    double output = getOutput(testWeights, input);

    return output;
}
```

---

**`LMBRDLL.def`** for exporting to MetaTrader Terminal platform:

```
LIBRARY "LMBRDLL"
EXPORTS
getWeights
testWeights
```

---

**`HeaderDLL.h`** for exporting to C++ app:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

    __declspec(dllexport) double *getWeights( double const *idata,
                                              int    const *aTopology,
                                              int           topSize,
                                              double const *aTV,
                                              double        validationDifference,
                                              int           vSize,
                                              int           tSteps,
                                              int           nVabs,
                                              double       *T
                                              );
    __declspec(dllexport) double testWeights( double const *rowWeights,
                                              double const *testData,
                                              int    const *aTopology,
                                              int           topSize,
                                              int           timeSteps,
                                              int           nVariables
                                              );
```

Comment: Did you check you really use as many cores as there are of threads spawned? It is very possible that your MQL4 thingy generates process-to-core affinity, which would be inherited y the OpenMP threads, preventing them from using all other (idle) cores than the one initially used by the application... Just a blind guess though.

Comment: Would you kindly post the **complete `MQL4`-context of the calls?** I.e. the relevant snippets of the **`{ *.mq4 | *.mqh | ... }`** file(s) -- including the **`#strict ... `**  et al directives and **`#import ... `** section(s) and all other compilation-modifying directives -- simply it is not possible to help you in any reasonable manner without these MetaTrader Terminal specific facts. Anyway, Adrijus, **welcome to the Wild Worlds of `MQL`**

Comment: StackOverflow encourages users to post questions, that are **MCVE** - a **M**inimum **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample of the observed problem, one strives to get help from the community members with. **Would be fair to update the post** and complete the `MQL4`-code as noted above, so as to form the MCVE.

Comment: Sorry for a tardy response. I have just updated the question with more details that I hope will be enough to grasp a picture of the problem I'm facing. Should there be anything else you would need to know just drop a comment. Regards

Comment: Still, is the `MQL4` code planned to be a **`Custom Indicator`**, a **`Script`** or an **`Expert Advisor`** in the MetaTrader Terminal code-execution realm?